# PHP SQL Avoid duplicate insertion of data

Tags: php, sql

I am currently programming a member management for our club in PHP. It should primarily also automatically register the membership fees.

For this I need an idea from you how to implement the following process:

1. the bank transactions are read in via an interface (incoming membership fees).
2. the IBAN, BIC, amount, booking date and name are read out
3. these data are written into the database table banktransactions_log

I have already implemented points 1 and 2. However, for point 3, I would avoid that when restarting the process, already existing transactions are written to the table again.

A simple IF query with SQL command would solve the problem, but would probably cause a lot of queries on each process restart. What is the most efficient and performant solution for writing only the new data into the DB during the read?

Update:
An unique ID is not given in the data.

```
{
      "iban": "DE555665465656545",
      "date": {
        "date": "2022-02-16 00:00:00.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
      },
      "amount": "200.75",
      "creditdebit": "credit",
      "description": "xyz",
      "name": "TSTS"
    }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of data you get from transactions? Is there some ID? Can you limit that data or do you always get everything? Is there a way to know which data was not present when you previously read transactions?

Comment: @TCFDS i put answer on my first post.

Comment: Can you know based on time which items are already processed? That would be the most efficient solution. If not, how you know, which items have been processed? Can there theorethically be two transactions with exactly equal data?

Comment: time is always 00:00:00 ):
Usually i will limit the data by date ranges. But for some reason maybe i could restart the process for the same daterange. In this case i want avoid duplicated content. Theorethically two transactions with exactly equal data could exist but this risk i would go.

Comment: without a unique identifier it is hard to do. You can make a unique index on the db, and include all the columns that you are storing from the incoming data, however if someone does 2 payments for the same amount from the same creditcard on the same date, it will get rejected, even if it is a legitimate transaction

Comment: I would consider an option to delete data from data range before processing it. It wouldn't be very effective if you reprocess data ranges very often. But also IF statements with complicated indexing is not optimal either